# SQLDataSource parameter insertion: Sanitisation and formatting

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am building a Web application and I want to allow users to insert records into a database.  The method that I came across is to take the information from text boxes and run this code:

```
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["ProductCode"].DefaultValue = txtProductCode.Text;
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Name"].DefaultValue = txtName.Text;
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Version"].DefaultValue = txtVersion.Text;
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["ReleaseDate"].DefaultValue = txtReleaseDate.Text;
try
{
    SQLDataSource1.Insert();
}
...
```

If I try to inject some SQL I get the error message:

> Message: String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

Does this method sanitise the parameters?  I am having a hard time finding this information because I am not sure if there is still a way to get around this error.  If it does not how should I go about sanitising the inputs?

Additionally, the ReleaseDate parameter seems to be currently reading as dd/MM/yyyy but is there a way to lock this so that the same code on a different system doesn't behave differently.  I am worried that if the code is run on a system with different regional settings it will use a different format.

Comment: That message just means one of your fields can't insert because what you're trying to insert is too long.  What are your column types and lengths?

Comment: What @sgeddes said. And yes you need to sanitize inputs. The AntiXss library helps. Also, look at entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

One of your field in the table is not long enough to insert the value. You need to check each of ProductionCode, name, Version and ReleaseDate for their length and increase them accordingly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196741(v=sql.80).aspx